# Sending a byte array with Java socket

Tags: java, sockets, arrays

I am programming an application which allows to download pdf files from a server. In my server side,  I get a  bytebuffer of my pdf file thanks to the pdfview library. I fill byte arrays with my byte buffer and then I send the byte arrays with a DataOutputStream.

Most of the time, I get good data in my client side, but sometimes I get an array filled with random numbers and so I can't rebuild my pdf file. I usually have the following error : "java.io.IOException: This may not be a PDF File"

So When I compare received data with sent data, it is totally different.
I can noticed that data in the server part are always correct

Any  help is appreciated

```
//Server side
this.in = new ObjectInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());
this.out = new DataOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream()); 
this.outObject = new ObjectOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());

this.res = this.in.readObject().toString();//I read the client order(GET home page, next page...)

//I get the bytebuffer from the pdf file------
this.file = new File (name+this.numFile+".pdf");
RandomAccessFile raf;
raf = new RandomAccessFile(this.file, "r");
FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
this.buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,0, channel.size());
//--------------------------------------------

int size = this.buf.capacity();
this.out.writeInt(size);//I send the size of my bytebuffer to the server

int size_array = 1000;
this.pack = new byte[size_array];
this.pack = clean_array();//I replace my variable by an array filled with zeros

for(long i=0;i<(size/size_array);i++){
buf.get(this.pack);
    this.out.write(this.pack);
    this.pack = clean_array();//I replace my variable by an array filled with zeros
}

//I have not sent the whole bytebuffer, the last byte array could have a different size
//I work out this size, I create the new bytearray and I send it---------------------
int byteLeft = size%size_array;
if(byteLeft>0){
    this.pack = new byte[byteLeft];
buf.get(this.pack);
this.out.write(this.pack);
this.pack = clean_array();//I replace my variable by an array filled with zeros
}

 //-------------------------------------------------

//Client side
int size_array = 1000;

pack =new byte[size_array];
pack = clean_array();

for(int i=0;i<((size/size_array));i++){     
    in.read(pack);
    buf.put(pack);
        pack = clean_array();
}

if(size%size_array>0){
//for the last loop, the number of bytes sent by the server is not equal to 1000
//So I create a byte array with the good size
   pack = new byte[size%size_array];
   in.read(pack);
   buf.put(pack);
   pack = clean_array();
  }
```

Comment: Could it be that your ObjectOutputStream and DataOutputStream on the same base stream somehow conflict each other?

Comment: You should be using write(byte[] b, int off, int len)  to write out part of a byte array.  That's the purpose of that method.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.in = new ObjectInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());
this.out = new DataOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
this.outObject = new ObjectOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
```

You don't need the DataOutputStream here, and you must create the ObjectOutputStream *before* the ObjectInputStream, otherwise you get a deadlock.

```
this.res = this.in.readObject().toString();//I read the client order(GET home page, next page...)
```

Bzzt. If the next object is a String this line of code will work, but it should have used a (String) cast, not toString(). If the next object *isn't* a String you have just corrupted it into something else.

```
this.pack = new byte[size_array];
this.pack = clean_array();//I replace my variable by an array filled with zeros
```

Pointless. (a) it already was full of zeros, and (b) if you insist on the second assignment what is the point of the first assignment?

The rest of your code is a long-winded and probably erroneous way of sending a file to the socket. Here's the easy way:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while ((count = fin.read(buffer)) > 0)
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);  // here 'out' is the socket output stream or whatever you want to wrap around it.
```